# Using a For Loop to run Macros on multiple sheets with ordered names like 1,2,3,4

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I have a created a Macro that copies data from a sheet from a different workbook->"data" onto the current workbook->"test"

```
Sub copy_data()

Windows("data.xlsx").Activate
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("test.xlsm").Activate
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

I want to make this macro run for multiple sheets which are in the "data" workbook.

I believe a loop should be efficient as the sheet names are 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5. So I was thinking of making a for loop, but im really stuck.

What I've done so far is shown below:

```
Sub Loopsheets()
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim iStart As Integer
Dim iEnd As Integer

iStart = 1
iEnd = 5

If iStart > 0 And iEnd > 0 And iEnd > iStart Then
  For i = iStart To iEnd
   Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
   Application.run "copy_data"
  Next i
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is untested but should work:

```
Sub copy_data(ws As Worksheet)

Dim dwb As Workbook
Dim dws As Worksheet

Set dwb = Workbooks("data.xlsx")
Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(1)

With dws
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).copy ws.Range("A1")
End With

End Sub



Sub Loopsheets()
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim iStart As Integer
Dim iEnd As Integer

iStart = 1
iEnd = 5

If iStart > 0 And iEnd > 0 And iEnd > iStart Then
  For i = iStart To iEnd
   Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(CStr(i))
   copy_data wks
  Next i
End If
End Sub
```

The name of the sheet is a string, by using an integer it will be calling the first sheet not sheet named "1".  So changing it to cstr(i) it will change the 1 to "1".

Comment: It should really be `copy_data wks` and not `copy_data (wks)`

Comment: This is why I always use `call` XD

Answer (score 1):

I simply combined your two routines and qualified your workbooks/worksheets. `thisworkbook` is assumed to be `test`.

```
Sub Loopsheets()
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim ws As Workbook
Dim i As Integer
Dim iStart As Integer
Dim iEnd As Integer

iStart = 1
iEnd = 5
Set wb = Workbooks("data")

For i = iStart To iEnd

    Set wks = wb.Worksheets(cstr(i)) 'edited per Scott
    With wks
        .Range("A1").Select
        .Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        .Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        Selection.Copy
    End With

    ThisWorkbook.Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Paste

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Should mention it's untested.

Comment: OP mentioned that the NAME of the sheets are 1,2,3,4,5.  They may or may not correspond with the index of the sheets.

Comment: Yea, use Scott's answer. It's also more object oriented.

Comment: Both should work if you change the worksheets(i) to worksheets(cstr(i)), then it is just which works better for the OP.  The OP may like yours better because it is in one sub not two.  Don't down sell it.

Comment: Well, I personally like yours better. It was my first thought too.